# Why did the accessories (clothings, masks, equipments, etc.) vanish along the person?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Everyone knows that the snap of Thanos at the end of *Avengers: Infinity War* ended the lives of half of all organisms in the Universe. But why did their accessories turn to dust along with the owner?

*For example:*

- Metal arm (from Winter Soldier)
- Vibranium suit (from Black Panther)
- Eye of Agamotto, Cloak of Levitation (from Dr. Strange)
- Jetpack (from Falcon)
- Iron Spider suit (from Spider-Man)

...and so on.

Was there any reason for the accessories disappearing as well? It would have expected that only the organic parts (the actual body) would disappear.